# Facebook sdk does insecure request to arbiter.php

Tags: facebook, oauth

I have a Facebook app which gets loaded from my server as an iframe inside a facebook fanpage.
I use the javascript sdk to handle the facebook authentication.

When I access the fanpage in IE through http, then the console shows the following https security error:
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=18

which causes the user to see the 'insecure content' warning.
I understand it has to do with the way IE handles the cross-domain iframe loading.

More details:

- Happens when FB.init is called (xd_arbiter.php is requested by the fb sdk when FB.init is called)
- Happens only in IE (specifically IE 9). No security warnings in Chrome or FF.
- Happens only when facebook is loaded through http, not https. I would have thought it would be the other way around...so facebook must be loading something over https even though the fanpage is loaded over http.

What I've tried:

- Setting FB._https = true before calling init. (does not work, deprecated)
- Made sure the sdk is loaded through https (in channel.html).
- Made sure all requests I do to my server is through https.

Here is my call to init:

```
FB.init({
  appId      : '{$appid}',
  status     : true,
  cookie     : false,
  xfbml      : true,
  oauth      : true,
  channelUrl : '//my_url.com/channel.html'
});
```

And the content of channel.html:

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

So how can I force the sdk to load the xd_arbiter.php over https so the warning goes away?

I understand the sdk is constantly evolving, but I first want to make sure I'm not doing something wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have all your assets on the same protocol, either HTTP, or HTTPS.

Then for remote requests, have you considered creating a PHP endpoints on your server, so your AJAX requests can, instead of calling cross domain URLs, call your PHP script, which is on the same domain, and then get PHP curl to do the cross domain stuff?